# Use Python variable in a MySQL Subquery

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
team = input("Enter the team name: ")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM `flash_data_archive` WHERE `event_id` IN (SELECT `alternate_id` from `event_list` where `category` = %s)" % team 

cursor.execute(sql)
```

What is the correct notation to have the the string the user entered for 'team' to be used for the category field in the sql subsuery?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `% team` from the string.  Instead, it should be an argument to `.execute`.

```
cursor.execute(sql, team)
```

This will properly escape it.